# DPDK rte_eth_rx_burst optimization

Tags: optimization, memcpy, dpdk

The scenario is my application (say A1) receives packet from another application (A2) over DPDK interface and it uses rte_eth_rx_burst to get the mbuf and then after getting this packet:

- we allocate a local buffer using malloc
- we do a memcpy of this mbuf data to the local buffer , so that this can be further processed by our application A1

Now the problem is this memcpy operation is consuming lots of CPU cycles. We are looking for some way to optimize this.
I am wondering if there is some way by which DPDK can be provided with local buffers and the data
can be directly copied in to that buffer so that the memcpy can be avoided or if you think there is some other better way then please suggest.

Though I am new to DPDK but tried to google a lot but didn't find any answers to this. I request if anyone can help here, thanks.

Following is the Pseudocode:

```
void dpdk_receive_from_App_2(void *port_id)    
{

    while(1)
    {
        packet_rcvd = rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id, 0, rx_buff, 128); 
        for (j = 0 ; j < packet_rcvd ; j++)
        {
            buf = (uint8_t *) rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset (rx_buff[j], uint8_t *, 32);
            loc_buff = malloc(512);
            memcpy(loc_buff, buf, 512); 
            send_loc_buff_for_processing(loc_buff);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to check sample DPDK application for exploring things related to optimizing the receive path but didn't find any thing.
I understand that rte_pktmbuf_attach_extbuf is used to optimize the Tx path for sending the burst but on the same lines I can't find any solution for optimizing the rx burst.

Comment: If you just need to copy to a separate buffer because of the mbuf segment, you can configure a single mbuf buf_len to be larger than the maximum mtu when initializing the mempool, and pass the mbuf directly when using it
Usually the driver prefers to put all the data in one buffer rather than multiple blocks